# Return multiple includes on object Ruby on Rails JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, activerecord

I have three models and am trying to output all of them as JSON in a single object.

The models and associations are as follows:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :subscription
  has_one :address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

I am trying to return all of the associated data as JSON using the following:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @customers = Customer.all
    render json: @customers, :include => :address, :subscription
  end
end
```

However this is returning a syntax error where ruby is expecting `=>` somewhere. Any help on how I can output all of this data would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone is looking I've just answered this question with the following syntax.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @customers = Customer.all
    render json: @customers, :include => [:address, :subscription]
  end
end
```

address and subscription needed to be passed in an array :)